# Routing Codeingter - Unique URL for each user

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

I have a web application that I made in codeigniter. This system has multiple users. I wanted to give each user their unique URL so for example.

```
www.mysite.com/user1

www.mysite.com/user2
```

If the user visits the url below;

```
www.mysite.com/user2/admim/addArticle
```

**admin/addArticle** function should implement and ignore the user2 in the url. I looked into routing but I was not successful at solving this problem.

Is this possible?

**What I tried so far:**

I added following in routes.php file
$route['(:any)'] = "home/index";

above did not work so I tried following guide at http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/217216/ which did not work either:

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You need to update your .htaccess file.

Comment: I added what I have tried so far now in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$route['user(\d+)/admim/addArticle'] = "controller/action";
```

you can see some examples here [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: The username of the user will not always be in the format user[numeric] it might also be "testuser". I am sure this will have a problem then.

Comment: then replace `'user(\d+)'` with `'(.*)/admim/addArticle'`?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and will let you know.
With this If I had say five functions in Admim controller then all five rules need to be added right?